# Where can I find blueberries rapidly?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

So many recipes need them

I went to the snow biome, I only found snowberry plants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding blueberry bushes in the wild can be difficult.  I've found the best way to get blueberries is to farm them, but to do that, you need seeds.  Seeds can be found randomly throughout the world, but certain perks can aid you in getting seeds.  For example, the [Living off the Land](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Living_Off_The_Land) perk once leveled up to level 3 allows you to craft seeds from crops.  At just level one of this perk, you harvest double the amount of crops from plants.

In a randomly generated world, I've found the best way to find blueberry bushes is to find farms in towns.  You can usually spot them by their big red barn buildings.  Sometimes (though not always) you can find blueberry bushes growing at these farms.  If you have the Living off the Land perk, each bush will yield you two blueberries, and then if you have the perk leveled to level 3, you can craft seeds out of the blueberries (1 seed per 5 berries), allowing you to plant and grow your own, which is ultimately one of the best ways to continuously get blueberries.

Comment: Note that plants re-grow and do not require you to re-craft the seeds like previous versions, so once you get 4-5 seeds, you really do not need any more.